# Cordova imagePickerEx plugin returns cached image too

Tags: jquery, caching, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have to make a form to post some user data with multiple images so I am using **[this](https://github.com/ratkop/-cordova-imagePickerEx)** plugin. My **Problem** is that if I select one image that I get a cached image too in the console even if I have set "cache view= false".

```
<code>
 var options = {
      maximumImagesCount: 10,
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
      quality: 80
    };
    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
        .then(function (results) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
          }  
        }, function(error) {
          // error getting photos
        });
        });
</code>
```

**Error**
    
    `4     738260   log      Image URI: file:///storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsA
    pp%20Images/IMG-20160426-WA0010.jpg
    5     738263   log      Image URI: file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.map/cach
    e/IMG-20160426-WA0010-774845115.jpg`

here I have selected only one image and I am getting a cached image too. But I want to get only one. 
So can anybody tell how to solve this?

Comment: There is a note in official plugin page which says - "The plugin returns images that are stored in a temporary directory. These images will often not be deleted automatically though. The files should be moved or deleted after you get their filepaths in javascript." So the behaviour is expected i guess. Did you try this plugin - https://github.com/ratkop/-cordova-imagePickerEx

Comment: thanks for responding and sorry too because I had removed the plugin mentioned in my post and installed your mentioned plugin about 2 days ago. So this seems that this cache issue remains with imagePickerEx plugin too.

Comment: Looking at the imagePickerEx plugin's source code (ImageFetcher.java), the cache files are maintained purposefully for performance. So you may have to write logic around this plugin to ignore cached files i guess.

Comment: I reinstalled the imagePicker plugin which is returning exact number of images that I have selected. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Reinstalled imagePicker or imagePickerEx plugin? It could be stale images issues if it works fine after reinstallation

Comment: first one imagePicker plugin

Comment: Glad it worked.Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched so much about this error and found out my silly mistake behind. Actually both of these plugins **imagePicker** and **imagePickerEx** don't work with *--live reload*. I was testing both of them with

```
`ionic run android -l -c`
```

thats why I wasn't able to get results as expected.
So always test them in ionic with

```
`ionic run android`
```